# Woocommerce remove new order header for admin emails

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I remove or hide new order header for admin emails?

My problem:

I would like to print my order, but the e-mail is bigger than 1 page. If I can remove the header my order fits is  only 1 page.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_heading_new_order','my_email_heading_customisation_function', 1, 2);
function my_email_heading_customisation_function($heading){
    $heading='';
    return $heading;
}
```